# why is java md5 generation is slower than php

Tags: java, php, md5

I obtained md5 of a string in java and php. It seems java's md5 generation takes a long time than php's md5 generation.

My test, test.java

```
start = System.nanoTime();
String md5 = Utils.md5("sample test string");
System.out.println(md5);
System.out.println((System.nanoTime()-start)/1000/1000);
```

Code for Utils.md5:

```
public static String md5(String stringToDigest) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if(stringToDigest == null) {
            return "";
    }
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] s = md.digest(stringToDigest.getBytes());
    HexBinaryAdapter hba = new HexBinaryAdapter();
    String md5 = hba.marshal(s);
    return md5;
}
```

Shows me:

```
CCEA62E4F30D422B123B9FDFB02CD496
20
```

test.php

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
echo md5('sample test string');
echo "\n".microtime(true)-$start."\n";
```

Shows me:

```
ccea62e4f30d422b123b9fdfb02cd496
0.00012302398681641
```

So php's md5 generation is taking only about 10-12 ms while java's is taking about 18-20 !!
Is my test wrong? If it's not **then is there another way to obtain md5 much faster than this?**

Edit:
To all people complaining about x is slower than y. I have asked this question because we have an application running and a major chunk is gonna be redesigned in java. We must serve every request within 30 ms. Now if only md5 generation is going to take this much time, project will be scrapped. 
Therefore I humbly ask for help. Those who want to help, much respect to them. Those who want to attack, please look for other questions

Comment: Do it 1000 times, or 10000 or 100000. Maybe Java has a high start up time because it needs to load additional libraries (under the hood). Or maybe it's just that sysout is slow, remove it from the timing.

Comment: -1 for "why is X faster than Y" question.

Comment: You're comparing two completely different technologies with completely different backends and software stacks...also do it more than one time to get some more meaningful results.

Comment: but then i have output in php's code too. still i removed it, it made no impact

Comment: to anyone complaining about my x is faster than y question. If you have anything to suggest how I can make modifications in x to make it nearly as fast as y, please do. Dont attack please. I have clearly asked is there any way to get it as fast as php.

Comment: you haven't proved it's slower

Comment: Why is a tortoise slower than a rabbit when running the same distance..? Eh..?

Comment: ok, then how do I prove it in any other way? I have also humbly mentioned if my test itself is wrong, please tell that. I am here not waste my time or anyone else's. If anyone really wants to help then please, otherwise look for other questions

Comment: The question itself is flawed. How can you compare two isolated languages..? I mean, comparing md5 generated from two java functions is a different thing. Comparing md5 in java to md5 in PHP is just wrong. Each language is different underneath. Components, architecture, etc etc.

Comment: generally it is said and observed that critical applications are coded in java for it's speed and security. Now I wondered why this component works so slow. That's it. And PLEASE see the edited question. That will make clear why I asked such a question in first place\

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java at all, but it doesn't take a Java programmer to note that even the time calculation is wrong. A nanosecond is a billionth of a second and you're only dividing by 1000 twice, like you'd do with microseconds. It's ~0.0002 vs ~0.00012, which isn't that much of a difference between the two.

Comment: 'ms' is the notation for milliseconds, which is a thousandth of a second. 1 ms = 1 second / 1000; 1 nanosecond = 1 second / 1000000000. The gap is 0.00000008ms, not 8ms ... and as many people already said - you shouldn't even be dealing with this comparison, it shows nothing.

Comment: Maybe error is in `Utils.md5` procedure? Can you post code of obtaining MD5?

Comment: sorry for not posting Utils.md5's code. I have now. Please check

Comment: @Narf: 0.00012 seconds shown by php is actually (0.00012*1000) = 0.12 ms. In case of java 1 ns/1000 = 1 microsec. 1microsec/1000 = 1 ms. So in I java got 20ms. I hit it again and again, got 18-21 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some tests and here are some explanations:

1. You have lot of boilerplate around generating md5. Printing md5 before takes 200ms on my pc, but you are probably testing without it.
2. When i replace

this

```
HexBinaryAdapter hba = new HexBinaryAdapter();
String md5 = hba.marshal(s);
return md5;
```

with

```
return Arrays.toString(s);
```

i get from 18ms to 6ms, so lot of time is taken on String conversion, probably because HexBinaryAdapter is xml related (I know that Arrays.toString will not covert it to correct string).

3.**Most important** When i take `MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");` out of measured area (made it static) i get to 224us (microseconds). That is part where java searches for suitable provider for generation of md5. **So in reality you are not measuring generation of MD5!**

Here is my code running much faster:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test7{
    static MessageDigest md; 
    static {
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    String md5 = md5("sample test string");
    long time = (System.nanoTime()-start)/1000;
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(md5);
  }
  public static String md5(String stringToDigest) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      if(stringToDigest == null) {
              return "";
      }

      byte[] s = md.digest(stringToDigest.getBytes());
      //HexBinaryAdapter hba = new HexBinaryAdapter();
      return Arrays.toString(s);
      //String md5 = hba.marshal(s);
      //return md5;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I will try this and let you know

Comment: NP. If you need to use MD5 as string you still need to find better way of conversion to string than HexBinaryAdapter